# Is there a command line tool to automatically setup and upload my python package to PyPi?

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging, command-line-tool

Each time I want to update my PyPi package, I always need to change the version number in `setup.py` file, and I need to remove the old `dist` and `build` folders. There are a bunch of commands I need to type in before I can see my updated package on PyPi website.

What's more, sometimes I want to upload my package to Test-PyPi rather than the real PyPi index, but the commands (upload url) are slightly different.

Is there a command line tool to automatically setup and upload my python package to PyPi or Test-PyPi? Or at least make the procedure more convenient?

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a command line tool on PyPi called [**auto-pypi**](https://pypi.org/project/auto-pypi/).

Simply run

```
$ pip install autopypi
```

to get and install this tool.

The use is very simple, run

```
autopypi your-package-root-directory
```

or

```
autopypi your-package-root-directory -r
```

will wrap up everything for you and upload your package to Test PyPi by default and the use of `-r` will upload your package to the Real PyPi index.

The project description is pretty clear. As it demonstrated, you might want to modify your own ***setup.py*** file a little bit for convenient version number updating:

```
version_number = input("Input the new version number you are going to use: ")

setuptools.setup(
    name="auto_pypi",
    version=version_number,
    ...)
```

Below is a detailed information about the command usage:

```
Usage: autopypi [OPTIONS] PKG_DIR

  Python command line tool to setup Python package automatically.
  Example:      $ autopypi your-package-root-directory -r
  Example:      $ cd your-package-root-directory
                $ autopypi . -r

Options:
  -r, --real          Use the real PyPi index (instead of test PyPi).
  --help              Show this message and exit.
```